# BiocCheck() for Bioconductor package submission, doesn't show the LINES with Error/Warn./Notes

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I am running BiocCheck("myPackage"), the results makes comments on how many places the problem exists, but doesn't comment on where the problem is. Is there any way to fix that?

```
BiocCheck("myPackage")

$error
character(0)

$warning
[1] "The following files are over 5MB in size: '.git/objects/pack/pack-3eae63a6b24d5861178a09b58eb0ec4d893242b0.pack'"

$note
[1] " Avoid sapply(); use vapply()"                                                                                                                                                     
[2] "Recommended function length <= 50 lines."                                                                                                                                          
[3] "Consider shorter lines; 103 lines (3%) are > 80 characters long."                                                                                                                  
[4] "Consider multiples of 4 spaces for line indents, 1258 lines(32%) are not."                                                                                                         
[5] "Cannot determine whether maintainer is subscribed to the bioc-devel\nmailing list (requires admin credentials).  Subscribe here:\nhttps://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/bioc-devel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :

```
BiocCheck:::checkFormatting("myPackage", nlines=Inf)
```

Works perfectly and shows all the lines with problems.